# Regular expression to find the http:// link out of the provided google search results link

Tags: python, regex

I have

```
/url?q=http://dl.mytehranmusic.com/1392/Poya/New/1392/7/8/1/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjIhcufvJXOAhWKrY8KHWjQBgQQFggTMAA&usg=AFQjCNF4phMtVM1Gmm1_kTpNOM6CXO0wIw

/url?q=http://mp3lees.org/index.php%3Fq%3DSia%2B-%2BElastic%2BHeart%2B(Feat.%2BThe%2BWeeknd%2B%2B%2BDiplo)&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjIhcufvJXOAhWKrY8KHWjQBgQQFggZMAE&usg=AFQjCNED4J0NRY5dmpC_cYMDJP9YM_Oxww
```

I am trying to find the `http://` link out of the provided google search results link.

I have tried `href = re.findall ('/url?q=(+/S)&', mixed)` where `mixed` is variable name in which the unformatted link is stored.

Comment: post your attempts

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: I have tried this!
 href = re.findall   ('/url?q=(+/S)&', mixed)

mixed is variable name in which the unformatted link is stored

those asterisks are not part of the link!

Comment: Please update the question itself with details, examples, requirements, and this attempt.

Comment: i dont know how my question got automatically updated!! i am a noob here on stack overflow! so dont know much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really need a regex to parse query strings. Use `urlparse`:

```
import urlparse
s = '/url?q=http://dl.mytehranmusic.com/1392/Poya/New/1392/7/8/1/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjIhcufvJXOAhWKrY8KHWjQBgQQFggTMAA&usg=AFQjCNF4phMtVM1Gmm1_kTpNOM6CXO0wIw'
res = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(s).query)
if (res['q']):
    print(res['q'][0])
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/k2DwOD)

If you absolutely want to have a regex solution for the reason you have not explained, I'd suggest

```
r'/url\?(?:\S*?&)?q=([^&]+)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aW2bM8/1).

The `(?:\S*?&)` part allows to match the `q` anywhere inside the query string, and `([^&]+)` will match 1 or more characters other than `&` and capture into a group returned with `re.findall`.